# Jetpack Compose - imePadding() for AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-alertdialog

The issue I faced was that I needed `AlertDialog` with some kind of List items (e. g. LazyColumn) and the `TextField` to search across these items. I wanted to display all the Dialog layout even when Keyboard is opened. But what I got is a Keyboard that cover some part of Dialog layout itself. I tried to use `imePadding()` for Dialog's `Modifier` but seems that Dialog ignoring that. I didn't find any solution for this on the Internet.

My code looks like so:

```
AlertDialog(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(AppTheme.margins.edge)
        .imePadding(),
    onDismissRequest = {
        searchText = TextFieldValue("")
        viewModel.clearSearchQuery()
        dismissCallback?.invoke()
    },
    text = {
           Column(
                modifier = Modifier.wrapContentHeight()
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(R.string.dlg_select_content_title),
                    style = AppTheme.textStyles.hugeTitleText
                )
                OutlinedTextField(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(top = AppTheme.margins.divRegular),
                    value = searchText,
                    placeholderText = stringResource(R.string.dlg_select_content_search_placeholder),
                    onValueChange = { newValue ->
                        searchText = newValue
                        viewModel.onSearchTextTyped(newValue.text)
                    }
                )

                RadioGroup(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
                    options = labels.map {
                        RadioOption(
                            title = it.name,
                            description = null,
                            selected = vmState.selectedLabel?.id == it.id,
                            tag = it.id
                        )
                    },
                    onOptionSelected = {
                        searchText = TextFieldValue("")
                        viewModel.clearSearchQuery()
                        viewModel.saveLabelSelection(it.tag as Int) {
                            dismissCallback?.invoke()
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
    },
    properties = DialogProperties(
        usePlatformDefaultWidth = false
    ),
    confirmButton = {
        // Nothing
    }
)
```

And the result:

[image]

I am not able to interact with several last items in list because Keyboard covers it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented a solution for this issue. The solution is quite ugly, but working. If someone knows a more elegant solution, feel free to write it in an answer in this question.

Even though the dialog ignores the `imePadding()` we still can set the height. So, first of all we should to know what screen height available above keyboard.

```
@Composable
private fun TrickyHeight(
    onHeightChanged: (Dp) -> Unit,
) {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .imePadding()
            .padding(bottom = 30.dp) // additional padding
            .onSizeChanged {
                onHeightChanged.invoke(with(density) { it.height.toDp() })
            }
    )
}
```

Next step is to create wrapper over `AlertDialog`:

```
@Composable
fun TrickyDialog(
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit,
    confirmButton: @Composable () -> Unit,
    dismissButton: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    icon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    title: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    text: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    shape: Shape = AlertDialogDefaults.shape,
    containerColor: Color = AppTheme.colors.surfaceColor,
    iconContentColor: Color = AlertDialogDefaults.iconContentColor,
    titleContentColor: Color = AlertDialogDefaults.titleContentColor,
    textContentColor: Color = AlertDialogDefaults.textContentColor,
    tonalElevation: Dp = AlertDialogDefaults.TonalElevation,
    properties: DialogProperties = DialogProperties()
) {

    val maxDialogHeight = remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
    TrickyHeight(onHeightChanged = { maxDialogHeight.value = it })

    AlertDialog(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .heightIn(0.dp, maxDialogHeight.value)
            .padding(AppTheme.margins.edge),
        onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest,
        confirmButton = confirmButton,
        dismissButton = dismissButton,
        icon = icon,
        title = title,
        text = text,
        shape = shape,
        containerColor = containerColor,
        iconContentColor = iconContentColor,
        titleContentColor = titleContentColor,
        textContentColor = textContentColor,
        tonalElevation = tonalElevation,
        properties = properties
    )
}
```

Also, do not forget to add correct `android:windowSoftInputMode` in Manifest: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Now you can use `TrickyDialog` instead of `AlertDialog`. Again, this solution is not elegant. But maybe it will be helpful for someone who faced the same issue. Also, this solution will not work properly for Landscape Screen Orientation.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

As of Compose UI 1.3.0-beta01, you can set `DialogProperties.decorFitsSystemWindows` to `false` and `imePadding()` will work.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/229378542
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.3.0-beta01

```kotlin
AlertDialog(
     modifier = Modifier.imePadding(),
     properties = DialogProperties(decorFitsSystemWindows = false),
     onDismissRequest = {
         // ...
     },
     title = {
         // ...
     },
     text = {
         // ...
     },
     confirmButton = {
         // ..
     },
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my customised dialog which has one TextField and two buttons. I wanted the dialog to move up when the soft keyboard is shown but in my project it just didn't do it, the soft keyboard always overlaps two buttons. I endedup creating a small project to test, and I finally found the issue is that because I set `<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>` in `res/values/themes.xml`.

This makes the dialog looks like:

[image]

Without above line, it just works.

[image]

I could not figure out why it has something to do with the dialog...I think it is a bug...